# Why do I still need CSRF token for Laravel Sanctum Token Auth?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api, csrf, laravel-sanctum

I am creating a chatting application. I use **React for frontend and Laravel Sanctum for api auth**.

I used **SPA auth for api**. But when I deployed it to Heroku, Heroku didn't allow the application to set cookies. So, I am trying to change my **SPA auth to Token based auth**.
The backend is working when I test with postman. Every routes are working. But when I call the api from my React app, it's saying **[419] CSRF token mismatch**.

**Is there anything to configure my React app to fix this problem?**
**Why do I still need CSRF token for token based auth?**

In case if you need to check my codes, I will add them below.

**React**

```
axios.post("https://www.mybackend.com/api/v1/login", {
  email: "user_1@gmail.com",
  password: "password"
});
```

**Laravel**

```
public function login(LoginRequest $request)
{
    try {
        if (Auth::attempt($request->only("email", "password"))) {
            return $this->successResponse([
                "user" => Auth::user(),
                "token" => Auth::user()->createToken(Auth::user()->id)->plainTextToken
            ]);
        }

        return $this->failResponse([
            "message" => "Wrong login credentials."
        ], 401);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new InternalErrorException($e);
    }
}
```

**api.php**

```
Route::group(["prefix" => "v1"], function () {
    Route::post("login", [\App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\AuthController::class, "login"]);
})
```

Comment: I know that I can add my routes to exceptions list in Csrf middleware. But is it the only way to solve this problem?

Comment: i guess you are using the `EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful` middleware? otherwise the routes in `api.php` do not have the CSRF check middleware applied (as there is no cookies, or session)

Comment: Oh. I got it. I just tested by removing EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful middleware and it's working now. Thank you.